# Cannot update 'column'; field not updateable

Tags: ms-access, exception

I have connected my application on visual studio using visual basic as programming language and MS Access as a database now when I want to save a new row in the database it is saying (Cannot update 'field1'; field not updateable)
And (column 'field1' does not allows nulls

I don't have any idea am still a beginner in visual basic and I am really blocked

Comment: Please add Visual Basic as a tag to your question and provide your actual code and more information about the database structure.

Answer (score 0):

Its likely field1 is an auto number field, and required field.

The first error-"(Cannot update 'field1'; field not updateable)" means the field's value are auto generated.

The second error-"And (column 'field1' does not allows nulls)" means the required property of the field in the table is set to true.

So go to the ms access database and check for the following

1. The field type (likely an auto number or auto generated)
2. The required property section of the field, check to be sure its not set to yes.

You might need to share more details like how are you updating the record set from visual studio.